# can not update Tensorflow for Conda

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, conda

I want to update Tensorflow from 1.14 to 2.1.0 but I'm not able to do it.

After I had installed it with command

> conda install -c anaconda tensorflow-gpu

print(tensorflow.**version**) shows me that I have version 1.14.0

The same after

> conda update tensorflow-gpu

Even after

> conda install https://anaconda.org/anaconda/tensorflow-gpu/2.1.0/download/win-64/tensorflow-gpu-2.1.0-h0d30ee6_0.tar.bz2

I get in command prompt:

```
Downloading and Extracting Packages
tensorflow-gpu-2.1.0 | ######################################################################################## | 100%
Preparing transaction: done
Verifying transaction: done
Executing transaction: done

C:\Windows\system32>set "KERAS_BACKEND="

C:\Windows\system32>python C:\Anaconda3\etc\keras\load_config.py  1>temp.txt

C:\Windows\system32>set /p KERAS_BACKEND= 0<temp.txt

C:\Windows\system32>del temp.txt

C:\Windows\system32>python -c "import keras"  1>nul 2>&1

C:\Windows\system32>if errorlevel 1 (
ver  1>nul
 set "KERAS_BACKEND=theano"
 python -c "import keras"  1>nul 2>&1
)
```

but I'm still on 1.14.0

Comment: A good question is why is this happening? Why is the default version for windows 1.14? Very annoying :-(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can update Tensorflow by typing this command to the Anaconda Prompt.

```
conda install -c conda-forge tensorflow=2.1.0
```

Hope this works!